# Installation with WUBI is asking to boot from live CD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

I installed 12.04 with WUBI along side my Windows 7,

When I did a reboot,  there is a choice to choose between "windows" & "ubuntu", but when I selected ubuntu, WUBI doesn't seem to read the installation? and it asked me to boot from CD again..

What should be my next steps to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Ubuntu By Going in **Add and Remove Programs** in Windows.  Try again to Install Ubuntu.